# WCF, Entity Framework (code first) vs LINQ to SQL

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, wcf-data-services

I'm new in WCF. In the application there will be CRUD and also some business rules.
Please recommend what should I chose EF or LINQ to SQL?

or WCF Data Services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to Pawel's points:

> Use EF. Linq to Sql is mainly in maintenance mode while Entity Framework is in active development.

I recommend exploring EF Code First.

[Scott Hanselman has a good intro post on EF Code First](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SimpleCodeFirstWithEntityFramework4MagicUnicornFeatureCTP4.aspx).

I'd also STRONGLY recommend [Julie Lerman's EF Code First book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B006C3CXTA) - it'll help answer many of the questions you may have as you begin development.

Finally, be sure to keep an eye on the [Data Access team's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/) - EF Code First is evolving VERY quickly and lots of great features are arriving regularly (my latest favorite being migrations in 4.3) :)

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

Use EF. Linq to Sql is mainly in maintenance mode while Entity Framework is in active development.